# Обновить JAVA_HOME Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, unix, path

Сделал downgrade Java 9 to Java 8. Системные переменные не обновились полностью. Что-то где то забыл но не могу понять где

```
andrey@HP-ProBook:$ java -version;javac -version
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
javac 1.8.0_161
andrey@HP-ProBook:$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

andrey@HP-ProBook:$ echo $PATH
/home/andrey/bin:/home/andrey/.local/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/db/bin

andrey@HP-ProBook:$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
Есть 3 варианта для альтернативы java (предоставляет /usr/bin/java).

  Выбор   Путь                                        Приор Состояние
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java              1091      автоматический режим
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      ручной режим
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1081      ручной режим
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java              1091      ручной режим

andrey@HP-ProBook:$ sudo update-alternatives --config javac
Есть 3 варианта для альтернативы javac (предоставляет /usr/bin/javac).

  Выбор   Путь                                     Приор Состояние
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/javac          1091      автоматический режим
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1081      ручной режим
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac          1081      ручной режим
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/javac          1091      ручной режим

andrey@HP-ProBook:$ cat ~/.profile 
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Помогите пожалуйста зарезолвить проблему.

Comment: В переменных path поменяй вот эту часть:
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/db/bin`
на актуальную. Для этого открой файл `etc/enviroment` любым текстовым редактором с правами суперпользователя, например:
`sudo gedit enviroment`. Не уверен, что это будет являться решением, поэтому не оформляю как ответ.

Comment: @YaraslauKhamenka

нету там джавы
`andrey@HP-ProBook:~$ sudo cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`

Comment: Добавь два пути, один к директории jdk/bin и один к jdk/jre/bin. Обрати внимание, что в path пути разделены двоеточием. Там же, в enviroment, можно прописать переменные HOME, с новой строки, например: `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_151"`

Comment: @YaraslauKhamenka сделал, вот что получилось
`PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin"`
теперь нужно удалить как-то 9ю Java из PATH
`echo $PATH
/home/andrey/bin:/home/andrey/.local/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/db/bin:/home/andrey/bin:JAVA_HOME:JRE_HOME`